# Preventing Duplicate Form Submissions Without JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am working on a project and i am building it using the mvc pattern. On successful form submission i redirect user and display a flash message ( success message using session ) i have no issues with users using the back button or refreshing. But if a user encounters an error when submitting a form the form is not redirected so the error can be displayed while keeping old form data to populate the field so users do not have to re-enter information.

The issue i am having is when users will spam the button for any reason. If i double click or spam the button an error is produced ( invalid form token error ) but the db interaction still takes place and inserts the form data. I am trying to find the best js alternative to maintain cross browser compatibility. Is js the way to go? Is their a php alternative?

Comment: what kind of data is being inserted in your DB? why wouldn't you just check the unique field (eg. email) to see if that record exists before inserting? If the record exists return a value to your View which can then display an error to the user.

Comment: As Graham says you can always check if the exact same record already exists in the database before inserting it. But I would definitely recommend JS for such tasks. It is much easier and faster to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using session vars, why not set a variable just after your DB update takes place. Then before every DB update check for this value. If false then update DB.

```
function updateDB(){
    if($_SESSION['already_submitted'] == true) return false;

    // DB update code

    // on success
    $_SESSION['already_submitted'] = true

    // rest of code
}
```